# How recover photos from a locked Android smartphone?

Tags: data-recovery, google-photos

A friend gives me her phone that she does not use anymore. This is a Oneplus 7 (android). She has set a pattern to lock the screen and does not remember it. So the smartphone is locked.

She's not sure that all her photos are recover so she wants me to save all of them before I reset the smartphone. USB debugging is not activated.

I see several options here:

- Use her Google account to deactivated the lockscreen (No idea if possible and  I have not found anything about this)
- Bypass the lockscreen and access the data (sonds illegal to me but
  maybe there is a way). All the solution I have found erase data.
- Make a copy of all the data of the smartphone (also sonds illegal)
- Use her Google account to force synchronisation between the smartphone and Google Photos from PC (I have no idea if this option exists)
- Any other solution?

Comment: Is the device encrypted?

Comment: @mashuptwice I can't find information about that. Oneplus does not give details about it and I am pretty sure the previous owner did not set encryption if this is a parameter in the phone

Comment: of course device is encrypted. there is no way to decrypt without pin

Comment: About illegal angle, ask your friend if she is okay if you try to break into her phone cause she cannot give the lock screen credentials and it seems unreasonable of her to ask you to get access to her photos without lock screen credentials. Once she gives a go ahead, you only have one angle to pursue. Exploiting a bug in your device and hoping that it gives you wireless access to the device or bypasses lock screen. Here is one full screen bypass exploit that *might* work on that device. https://bugs.xdavidhu.me/google/2022/11/10/accidental-70k-google-pixel-lock-screen-bypass/

Comment: @Firelord the .dismiss() vulnerability cannot decrypt device. but yeah nice exploit :)

Comment: @alecxs that is correct. It does not decrypt the device. It  temporarily bypasses the lock screen. So if the screen times out, OP has to run the exploit again. :) But the exploit enables access to the home screen which is sufficient to get photos and other user data from internal storage.

Comment: @Firelord, perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta answers suggesting exploits become outdated very soon. I don't think posting an answer in this case would do any good. Besides, OP didn't respond to my comment, so I cannot write with confidence that my answer would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the option have been tested. She remembered her pattern so I am able to unlock the phone. Firelord's solution is probably the best option in this case. But as he said, exploiting a bug may be outdated very soon.