# extract data from phone with oem unlocked and usb debugging enabled password?

Tags: data-recovery, usb-debugging, mobile-data, android-10, lost-phone

My huawei mate 20 lite phone was stolen in afu state, there is a pin code on the screen, but usb debugging is on and I removed the oem lock, in this case, can my data on the phone be accessed?

Comment: depends on lock screen is easy to guess. without pin code, no data can decrypted. guesswork: no (not sure about that bug though) https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249450/how-recover-photos-from-a-locked-android-smartphone?noredirect=1#comment335751_249450 usually first thing thief does is power off and factory reset (to avoid beeing tracked)

Comment: i think this was done by someone i know to access my data, because oem lock is unlocked and usb debugging is active in safe mode, is there no chance to install root file or delete pin directory with command?

Comment: deleting locksettings.db (even in afu state) will destroy encryption, that's no option. of course - if you **disabled** encryption then all it needs is boot into TWRP recovery and do anything with your data

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/196230

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143878

Comment: @alecxs what do you mean if I disabled encryption? I did not its alredy have a pin code but just oem unlocked and usb debugging enabled

Comment: @alecxs If it is reset to factory settings, the data will be lost. Even if it does, it can only access my encrypted data. Am I missing something

Comment: no. you are right. it was only a question about encryption state of device before theft. if you are sure it was encrypted - no worry about offline attacks

Comment: @alecxs So, if OEM unlocking and usb debugging are turned on, is it possible to switch to safe mode and remove my password or make a copy of my data with the help of command line or sd card with rom loaded without data loss? I read that it is possible to bypass the screen pin code with the sim card trick, is it possible to access my data?

Comment: @Firelord Could you help me about this problem bro pls?

Comment: remote erase your device https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager